# Correct usage of "evangelize"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I attended a meeting by a very senior person at my work place. The meeting concerned the theme of Data analytics and Big Data.

The presentation mentioned the goal as "evangelize raw data".
Is this usage correct and appropriate?

Comment: Hello, karmanaut. A good question on this site will show evidence of attempts to find an answer from existing sources, according to the help center.

Comment: What did "evangelize raw data" appear to mean? Unless the evangelizing was something actually done *to* the data (after which they would presumably no longer be wholly raw), it is likely some preposition or phrase such as "on behalf of" might be needed between *evangelize* and *raw data.*

Comment: It's a reasonable figurative use, probably meaning that the goal was to promote awareness of, use of, or preference for raw data.  I suppose the intent could also be to evangelize to the users of raw data and try to get them to convert to something else. To be sure which was intended, we'd have to see/hear the rest of the presentation; the phrase is ambiguous in isolation, which is bad practice but not incorrect.

Comment: It's metaphorical. 'evangelize' being used as 'promote'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read it as "evangelize the use of raw data in analysis", but that's far too wordy for the typical PowerPoint slide.  I'd simply assume it was shortened for easy consumption.

See [The Gettysburg PowerPoint](http://norvig.com/Gettysburg/) for a stirring example of the impact of using PowerPoint slides to reach your audience.